# Mail icon in systray missing for mails that I move by a rule

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I am using Outlook 2013 (had the same problem with Outlook 2010) and I have a little problem:

If I receive an email, I get the usual envelop icon in the systray and a desktop notification. Now I have a rule to move an email to a subfolder (nothing more, just move) if it's from a specific person. For this mails the envelop is missing.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

Probably because the rule for the notification is for new emails in your inbox only.

[Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/show-an-envelope-icon-in-the-taskbar-and-play-a/7c5608af-dca4-46c7-ad40-bd959a2c1402)

You do have some freedom here about setting up other notifications, but it depends on how many rules/folders you have as to [whether this is applicable](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/newmailalert.htm).

Comment: I am not talking about the desktop alert, that part is working or at least I can add it to the rule so it will show. It's just the mail icon in the systray that is not showing up.

Comment: @Feroc I've updated my answer